# When registering a domain using a static IP and the A Record, do I need to set the Nameservers also?

Tags: ip-address, domains, domain-registrar

I am attempting to set up a server that has a static IP address and I want to register a domain name to point to it. Having always used shared hosting in the past, I am unsure what to tell my domain to point at.

Do I just put the IP for the A record and delete the name server records?

Comment: This seems off-topic for SU, shouldn't it be in http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NameServer is needed for every domain. Just put the static IP as an A record in your registrar's control panel.

(If your registrar was different from your shared hosting provider in the past, you would have done the same even for shared hosting).